# Как изменить цвет списка файлов в Linux

Tags: bash, linux

Как сменить цвет выводимого списка файлов в Linux? Командой ls я вывожу список файлов, все файлы темно-синего цвета, что не очень хорошо читается. Помогите мне пожалуйста изменить цвет.